# Debayering change the image color statistics (making auto white balance wrong)

Tags: image-processing

I am playing with debayering and auto white balancing. I have access to my own build camera so I can get raw images out of it.

I saved an image in RAW mage (the same way that I came out of camera sensor) and trying to process it in pc using test codes that I wrote in C#. The aim to understand debayering and auto white balancing and then write code in c/c++ on camera to do these type of things on camera.

To do auto white balancing, I developed code to implement grey world algorithm. If I apply this algorithm on raw image and then do debayering, the debayering change the image statistics and generate some colour cast.

How to do debayering that it doesn't change the colour space?

Comment: Any reason you're doing the auto white balance before de-bayering? Why not after?

Comment: @Zaphod: image is somehow convolved during depayering and hence, and for that reason, I like to do it before debayering. Also I like to find RGB gains and apply them to sensor to get a better image in different lighting condition.

Comment: Can you apply the white balancing after debayering, and then based on what you find, modify the RGB gains for the next frame so that they get applied before debayering?

Comment: @Zaphod the plan was as you explained, but since debayering change color space, I can not do that. What I can calculate as RGB gains after debayering is not valid as debayering changes color space.

Comment: This is an intuitive answer, so I'm not 100% certain about it. Debayering is usually carried out using a linear equation (probably bi-linear interpolation) on the RGB values. Once you have computed the gain corrections, you may need to scale them according to the debayering equation.